# Replace diagonals of a 2D array with python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, diagonal

I have the following 2D array

```
A=([[1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 16])
```

And I want to replace the main diagonal by the array

```
a = ([0,2,15,20])
```

Therefore, the results must be

```
A=([[0, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 2, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 15, 12],
    [13, 14, 15, 20])
```

I tried with np.diag(a, k=0) but it doesn't work because np.diag() creates a diagonal 2D array with the array "a".

Is there a way to do that with numpy? 
The above example is the simplest one. I would like to be able to change not only the mail diagonal but all diagonals.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**`np.fill_diagonal(..)`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) for that. Like the documentation says:

> **`numpy.fill_diagonal(a, val, wrap=False)`**
>
> Fill the main diagonal of the given array of any dimensionality.

For example:

```
np.fill_diagonal(A, 20)
```

We here thus *broadcast* `20` over the entire diagonal.

You can also fill the diagonal with different values, like:

```
np.fill_diagonal(A, [0,2,15,20])
```

For example:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((4,4))
>>> np.fill_diagonal(a, [0,2,15,20])
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., 15.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., 20.]])
```

In case you want to change other diagonals, then it is a matter of mirroring the array. For example for the *antidiagonal*, we can use:

```
np.fill_diagonal(A[::-1], -20)
```

Then we thus get:

```
>>> A = np.zeros((4,4))
>>> np.fill_diagonal(A[::-1], -20)
>>> A
array([[  0.,   0.,   0., -20.],
       [  0.,   0., -20.,   0.],
       [  0., -20.,   0.,   0.],
       [-20.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

If we do not take *superdiagonals* and *subdiagonals* into account, a *n* dimensional matrix, has *n×(n-1)* diagonals. We can assign this by mirroring one or more dimensions.

Comment: I love your answer (discovering numpy functions is lovable), but he asked for the main diagonal, as long as **any** diagonals if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks, it is a good answer. I have changed the array "a" because it was a bad example with all the elements equal to 20.

Comment: @IMCoins: well this fills only the *main* diagonal (it is even in the documentation) :)

Comment: @DiegoDZ: that is not the problem, you can also pass an iterable, and it will then *not* perform broadcasting.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) on indexing into multidimensional arrays.

```
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), np.arange(A.shape[1])] = [0,2,15,20]
```

**Note**: @WillemVanOnsem's answer is the best answer for filling in main diagonal but this is the best general way for getting/setting any subset of elements in a multidimensional array!

For example to change the other diagonal:

```
A[-np.arange(1, A.shape[0] + 1), np.arange(A.shape[1])] = [0,2,15,20]
```