# How to distribute a Numpy array along the diagonal of an array of higher dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three two dimensional Numpy arrays `x`, `w`, `d` and want to create a fourth one called `a`. `w` and `d` define only the shape of `a` with `d.shape + w.shape`. I want to have `x` in the entries of `a` with a zeros elsewhere. 
Specifically, I want a loop-free version of this code:

```
a = np.zeros(d.shape + w.shape)

for j in range(d.shape[1]):
    a[:,j,:,j] = x
```

For example, given:

```
x = np.array([
    [2, 3],
    [1, 1],
    [8,10],
    [0, 1]
])

w = np.array([
    [ 0, 1, 1],
    [-1,-2, 1]
])

d = np.matmul(x,w)
```

I want `a` to be

```
array([[[[ 2.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 3.,  0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  2.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  3.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  2.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  3.]]],


       [[[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  1.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]],


       [[[ 8.,  0.,  0.],
         [10.,  0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  8.,  0.],
         [ 0., 10.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  8.],
         [ 0.,  0., 10.]]],


       [[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  1.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]]])
```

Comment: You could extract it like that, but how to set it?

Comment: Maybe this could work in combination with broadcasting https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569377/7919597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569377/7919597) inspired the following solution:

```
# shape a: (4, 3, 2, 3)
# shape x: (4, 2)

a = np.zeros(d.shape + w.shape)
a[:, np.arange(a.shape[1]), :, np.arange(a.shape[3])] = x
```

It uses Numpy's broadcasting (see [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html) or [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)) im combination with [Advanced Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to enlarge `x` to fit the slicing.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have an even simpler solution: `a = np.tensordot(x, np.identity(3), axes = 0).swapaxes(1,2)`
The size of the identity matrix will be decided by the number of times you wish to repeat the elements of `x`.